# How to merge vertices fill in a certain manner

Tags: modeling, vertices

[image]
[image]
[image]

Trying to vertices fill in a certain way, but no matter what I do I get this double triangle that protrudes out. The last image is what I'm trying to create.

Any inputs would be great. Thank you

Comment: Is your mesh crossing over to the other side? Try turning on Bisect and Flip options as well. Just selecting the middle two vertices and repeatedly pressing "F" (Fill) should result like this: https://i.imgur.com/vM3pC3o.mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell what you have tried when you say "no matter what I do", but here are some possibilites how to get what you want.

No matter which method you use, make sure all faces are oriented correctly. Go to *Overlays* and enable *Face Orientation*, if they are all showing blue, everything's fine.

[image: face orientation correct]

If some are red, either select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and *Recalculate Normals* with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. If some are still showing red, select only those and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *Normals* > *Flip*.

[image: flipped red faces]

Now on to how get the connection between nose and upper lip. The twisted triangles look like you have the *Loop Tools* addon enabled and used the *Bridge* option. If this is the case, try the following:

Go to to the tool menu at the bottom left of the viewport and enable *Reverse*. If this still isn't working correctly, try to change the *Twist* value to something different than 0, positive or negative.

[image: bridge tool options]

Without using the *Bridge* tool, you can create those connections in *Edge Select* mode like this:

1. Select an upper and a lower edge, hit <kbd>F</kbd> to connect them.
2. Now choose either the edge down the center or the other upper and
   lower edge and hit <kbd>F</kbd> again.

[image: fill edges]

Another way would be to select all 6 vertices in *Vertex Select* mode.

1. With all 6 vertices selected, hit <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face between them. This will most likely be an N-gon.
2. Select the two vertices in the center and hit <kbd>J</kbd> to split the N-gon between them.

[image: n-gon split]